# specifying server port (not postgres port) for pg_dump / psql

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, psql

I have a server named as servername.mydomain.com. I can do ssh to this server using a port number X using:

```
ssh  myusername@servername.mydomain.com -p X
```

From this server I can run:

```
psql -h localhost -d myDatabase -U myusername -p DBPORT
```

Instead of having to login using ssh I want to be able to use psql as:

```
psql -h servername.mydomain.com:X -d myDatabase -U myusername -p DBPORT
```

Is this possible? I tried this but I am getting the message: could not translate hostname ...

Comment: leave out the :x it's not part of the hostname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

leave out the :x

```
 psql -h servername.mydomain.com -d myDatabase -U myusername -p DBPORT
```

You may need to edit the `listen_addresses` directive in `postgrersql.conf` (and restare poastgresql.

Alternatively you can tunnel the postgres connection.

```
ssh  myusername@servername.mydomain.com -p X -R DBPORT:127.0.0.1:DBPORT
```

then on another command-line

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -d myDatabase -U myusername -p DBPORT
```